# Node express from webserver

Tags: node.js, http, express

I have been developing a standalone app for an event exhibition. This comprised of a backbonejs frontend with a node express server backend for saving data. At the event this will run over localhost fine but how can I make the express server be accessed via normal http. I.e the backend responds when app is added to my webserver for client review

Any ideas.

G

Answer (score 0):

Servers available at localhost should respond to http requests if your firewall is open. If you are behind a router, you need to configure it to forward requests to your machine. NAT is the simplest (and least safe) way.

Comment: So I need to explain this a little more. The server part of my app is currently accessed when im testing locally via localhost:3333/server/route. Is it possible to set this up on my hosting environment. e.g: dev.domainname.com/server/route? Having my own machine broadcast out of local network is not an option.

Comment: If your hosting environment supports installing node it's very straightforward to install node, transfer your source files, install packages and start node just like your local environment. Look for guides for this from your host and node documentation.